# How to set a Javascript-HTML variable from a Android code

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to set the value of a global variable from Android code.

```
               mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                       "loginID = '"+nicu_app.urlSelected+"'; " +  
                       "})()");
```

but when I load the webpage in a webview and check to see if this variable has been set by the Android code, I don't see any positive results.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sana.

Comment: have you defined a javascript interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I was able to set the javascript variable, which was declared global in the HTML-Javascript page and then use the

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function () { " +
                           "setVariable("+valueToSetInHtmlPage+");" +
                           "})()");
```

and at the HTML webpage I had

```
function setVariables(a,b) {
    loginID = a; 
    serverUrl = b;
}
```

where `loginID` and `serverUrl` are both global

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [`addJavascriptInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface) to create a proxy between Java and the webview Javascript